# how to convert unarranged dates to the default date format in R

Tags: r, date, date-format

I'm working with hundreds of stores data with R. 
And there is store open data.
But it's unarranged, for example "20061019". 
I'd like to convert into "YYYY-MM-DD" format.
Plz teach me how to deal with it. thx :)

Comment: Have a look at `?as.POSIXct` and `?strptime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> paste(substr(aa,1,4),"")
>   [1] "2006 " "2016 "
>   paste0(substr(aa,1,4),"-",substr(aa,5,6),"-",substr(aa,7,8))
>   [1] "2006-10-19" "2016-09-09"

Comment: Suppose your stores data are save in data object aa:
paste0(substr(aa,1,4),"-",substr(aa,5,6),"-",substr(aa,7,8))

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.Date` with `format` argument (from `base R`)

```
as.Date("20061019", format = "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2006-10-19"
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this is with `lubridate` `ymd` function like this

```
library(lubridate)  
ymd("20061019")
```